# Uploading audio files in php not saved in designated folder?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, uploading

This is my form.php

```
      <form name="form" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?php $id=$_REQUEST['id1']; ?>
        <label>Category: </label><?php echo
        '<input type="text" name="category" onfocus="blur()" value='.$id.'>'?></br>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="32"></br></br>
            <label>Type:</label>
            <select name="type">
                <option value="Audio">Audio</option>
                <option value="Video">Video</option>
                <option value="Read">Read</option>
                <option value="Quiz">Quiz</option>
            </select>
            <label>Description:</label></br>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="description"></textarea></br>                  </br>
            <label>File:</label>
            <input type="file" name="files"/></br>
            <input type="submit" value="upload" name="up">
        </form>
```

and my upload.php

```
        include("connect.php");


        if(isset($_REQUEST['up']))
        {
        $nagan=$_FILES['files']['name'];    
        $tmp_loc=$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];

         echo $nagan;
         echo $tmp_loc;
            $bookCover="modules/".$nagan;

            move_uploaded_file($tmp_loc,$bookCover);

            $sql="INSERT INTO modules (name, type, description, filename, category)VALUES('$_POST[name]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[description]','$bookCover','$_POST[category]')";

           mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_affected_rows();

    if($count==1)
    {

      echo "File $nagan Successfully Uploaded!";

    }else
      echo "Error!";


      }

    ?>
```

Uploading images and pdf files work fine but when i try to upload audio files it does not show in the designated folder (modules folder) but it saves a value in the database. Also, when i try to upload a video file the upload.php does not work at all. Please help me. I am trying to figure this out for two days now. help.

Comment: Are your audio/video files below the upload size limit?

Comment: What is the value of upload_max_size and post_max_size in your php.ini? And what is the size of the audio files you tried to upload? `ini_get('upload_max_filesize');ini_get('post_max_size');` these two shows you the result in bytes.

Comment: @Maerlyn and kovge my audio file is 7.72MB and i don't know the maximum value of the upload_max_size and post_max_size..i'll check it right now

Comment: ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M

@Kogve is this the one i need to change?

Comment: Yes, change to the excepted maximum filesize. And you should change post max size, and show the maximum value near the file input form to show users what they can upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini`? And what is the size of the audio files you tried to upload?

```
  print ini_get('upload_max_filesize').' MBytes (Upload max size) <br/>'.
        ini_get('post_max_size').' MBytes (Post Max Size)';
```

these two shows you the result in MBbytes.
If this is too small,

```
1) Try: ini_set('upload_max_filesize','the size you need');
        ini_set('post_max_size','the size you need');
2) If the 1) does not works : 
  try to set the value of this properties in your php.ini  
      (on linux use this command to find: locate php.ini, or find / -name php.ini)
      (on windows use the file search tool)
  restart apache /if you use apache/ or the webserver deamon what you use
3) If you could not do 1) or 2)  (because do not have access this property) contact to the server administrator.
```

And before these all try to upload small (smaller than 1MB) audio and video files.

Answer (score 0):

The following options are relevant:

PHP: upload_max_filesize (in php.ini or .htaccess only, won't work using ini_set())

PHP: post_max_size

PHP: max_input_time

and possibly

Apache: LimitRequestBody

Answer (score 0):

There may be permission problem in php.ini for max upload size.

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize

```
post_max_size = 10M
```

You can change it too, and restart the server.

Comment: it works now thanks.. but is it possible to change the file size to 1GB or higher? or will i just have to place 1024M?

Comment: never mind.. i just changed it to 1024M and it works..thanks again